# How can the client-side listen for anything outside the web page without the server-side?

Tags: javascript, client-side

What I want to do is use JavaScript (or some other client-side way) to listen for events occurring *outside* the web page **without** server-side help.  It might look like this:

---

```js
// tester.js

cses = new ClientSideEventSource("JSEventSource.js");
cses.onmessage = function(event){
    // do something 
}
```

---

```js
// JSEventSource.js

CSES_return("CSES has been run!");
// note how this is client-side
```

---

The problem here is that this is all imaginary because those functions (sadly) don't exist.  AJAX calls to JS files don't work.  Here is an example of it's usage:

```js
function getNotifications()
{
  var cses = new ClientSideEventSource("JSEventSource.js");
  cses.onmessage = function(event){alert(event.data)}
}
function sendNotification()
{
  CSES_return("You have got a notification!");
  // this does not give an error even if this is not used in CSES mode
  // which is started with: new ClientSideEventSource("jsfile.js");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="getNotifications()">Get Notifications</button>
    <button onclick="sendNotification()">Send Notification</button>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- You will get errors because ClientSideEventSource and CSES_return do not exist -->
```

That is basically a messaging system (with a certain message) that doesn't use any Server-Side code.  Is there anything to replicate this?

Comment: From what I know, it is impossible to connect users together without some kind of server.

Comment: @Samathingamajig : That is what I thought, but I was just asking if there was a way.  Thank you though!